# When should one protect answers?

Tags: discussion

Just got the privilege to protect answers however I'm not quite confident with it yet.

Could anyone let me know **when should one protect a question?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: please don't. Leave it to the mods.

Edit:

Here's my reasoning - this site is under a lot of scrutiny. Since Mage Stack Day I have had 15 or so people contact me and say that they feel this isn't a very open or accepting place for newcomers.

A protect on a question or answer would only be used properly in the case of dozens of duplicate answers or a question that is being repeatedly edited.

In an effort to keep these complaints down let us be the bad guys when we have to be - and we'll try not to be - and you keep doing what you're doing.

Some reading about when to protect:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/52765/157698

From the article:

When should I protect or unprotect a question?

> Do protect questions that are attracting a lot of non-answers or very
>   poor answers (spam, etc.) from new users. Don’t protect questions just
>   because they’re linked to on a high-traffic news site. Do unprotect
>   questions that aren’t currently attracting a lot of attention and
>   don’t have a long history of unproductive answers.

Comment: Fair enough. What about long answer ? ^^ As you asked me I'll leave it to you guys but out of curiosity I wanna know how do you guys decide what to protect ?

Comment: Thanks for that I appreciate the clarification